# Devexpress lookup edit select one fill in rest lookups

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, devexpress, xpo, gridlookupedit

I'm working on program which uses xpo collection to get and update data from and to database. I setted up lookupedit to get data from another database(country name) I would like another lookupedit (country code) to be filled in automatically after country name is selected.

Here is XPO collection:

```
Private Countries As New XPCollection(Of clCountry)(UOW)
```

and here is lookup code:

```
CountriesLookupRepo.DataSourceConnect("Name", "Name", Countries)
CountryCodeLookUp.DataSourceConnect("ISO2", "ISO2", Countries)
```

How can I link them up so that ISO2 will be filled automatically after Name is selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do it.

In case someone else is wondering, this is how I did it :

```
Dim Country As clCountry = CountriesLookupRepo.GetDataSourceRowByKeyValue(e.Value)
                Apt.CountryCode = Country.ISO2
                Apt.RegionName = Country.Region
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through this DevExpress thread which describes most of cases to implement this functionality.

[How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A237)

> GridControl, TreeList, and VGridControl provide a special event that
>   is raised when a cell editor is activated: ShownEditor. This is the
>   best moment to replace the LookUp editor's data source with the
>   collection filtered by an appropriate criterion.

example:

```
Private Sub gridView1_ShownEditor(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim view As ColumnView = DirectCast(sender, ColumnView)
    If view.FocusedColumn.FieldName = "CityCode" AndAlso TypeOf view.ActiveEditor Is LookUpEdit Then
        Dim edit As LookUpEdit = CType(view.ActiveEditor, LookUpEdit)
        Dim countryCode As String = CStr(view.GetFocusedRowCellValue("CountryCode"))
        edit.Properties.DataSource = GetFilteredCities(countryCode)
    End If
End Sub
```

and for more information related to your quest of binding XPO objects with LookupEdit check this KB example:

[How to: Bind an XPCollection to a LookUp](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/CustomDocument2000)

example:

```
XPCollection xpCollectionPerson = new XPCollection(typeof(Person));         
xpCollectionPerson.DisplayableProperties = "Name;Group!Key";
gridControl1.DataSource = xpCollectionPerson;

XPCollection xpCollectionGroup = new XPCollection(typeof(PersonGroup));
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit lookUpRI = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
lookUpRI.DataSource = xpCollectionGroup;
lookUpRI.DisplayMember = "GroupName";
lookUpRI.ValueMember = "Oid";
gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(lookUpRI);
// Associate the LookUpEdit editor with the "Group!Key" column. 
(gridControl1.MainView as ColumnView).Columns["Group!Key"].ColumnEdit = lookUpRI;
```

Hope this help.